# Is it possible to create multiple users in OpenXava free version?

Tags: java, security, openxava

The only user available in my OpenXava application is 'admin'. I know that using XavaPro I have a complete users and roles management system for my OpenXava application, but XavaPro is a commercial product.

Can I add additional users to my OpenXava application using the open source edition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Go to the folder 'properties' inside your project. There you can find a file called naviox-users.properties, with this content:

```
# In plain OpenXava the users are added here in the form user=password
# If you want full management of users, roles and modules stored in database, 
#   get XavaPro from here: http://www.openxava.org/xavapro

admin=admin
```

Edit it, and add all the users you want with the pair user=password, in this way:

```
# In plain OpenXava the users are added here in the form user=password
# If you want full management of users, roles and modules stored in database, 
#   get XavaPro from here: http://www.openxava.org/xavapro

admin=admin
john=sjr3ji
juan=mso2rl
dorotea=mosoko
```

You have to restart your application in order it has effect.

To learn more about security and user management with OpenXava look at: https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/security_en.html